# How can I abstract code out of a template by using functions.php

Tags: templates

I'm creating a template, and one of the files is getting overloaded with pig-ugly mixed html and php.

At first I thought that maybe I should cut out chunks of the code, and call them  using include().

Then I thought - maybe there is a wordpress way to do things. Perhaps I should abstract out my logic from the templates, by putting the custom loop in functions.php, and then calling it somehow from the template.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is personal preference and there are many ways it can be done.  I like to keep my templates as clean as possible and use [get_template_part()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_part) to include the various parts.

For parts of code that is used often I like to create functions and call the functions in the templates.